# OSGI bundle for GF4 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet - ClassNotFound

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, osgi

This is my first attempt to make an osgi bundle with servlet inside. Having googled I made this budnle and it was successfully started by glassfish 4. But when in browser I try to open it I get

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not
>   found by ... [299]    at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)

My manifest file:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>  Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
>  Bundle-SymbolicName:
>   tutu 
>  Bundle-Version: 1.0.0 
>  Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
>   Web-ContextPath: /tutu 
> Import-Package:
>   javax.servlet,javax.servlet.annotation, javax.servlet.http

As far as I understand osgi doesn't import these packages although I can be wrong. Please, help to fix this problem.

EDIT:
I found the mistake. Order in MANIFEST makes sense. So the final manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: tutu
Bundle-Name: tutut
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Import-Package: javax.servlet,javax.servlet.annotation, javax.servlet.http
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes
Web-ContextPath: /tutu
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD servlet-api.jar in build path and try.